# Image PIL - "ValueError: Band index out of range"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am playing around with the code in [this notebook](https://github.com/akTwelve/tutorials/blob/master/image_composition/BasicImageComposition.ipynb).

When I load my own foregrounds, for certain images saved as '.png' I get this error:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-63-1464e7681a29> in <module>()
     21     foreground_path = random.choice(foregrounds)
     22     background_path = random.choice(backgrounds)
---> 23     composite, mask, bbox = compose_images(foreground_path, background_path)
     24 
     25     composite_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'image_{0:04d}.png'.format(i))

<ipython-input-47-53344b89732e> in compose_images(foreground_path, background_path)
      4     assert os.path.splitext(foreground_path)[1].lower() == '.png', 'foreground must be a .png file'
      5     foreground = Image.open(foreground_path)
----> 6     foreground_alpha = np.array(foreground.getchannel(3))
      7     assert np.any(foreground_alpha == 0), 'foreground needs to have some transparency: {}'.format(foreground_path)
      8 

~/anaconda3/envs/ctlearn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in getchannel(self, channel)
   2082                     'The image has no channel "{}"'.format(channel))
   2083 
-> 2084         return self._new(self.im.getband(channel))
   2085 
   2086     def tell(self):

ValueError: band index out of range
```

So the culprit code is `np.array(foreground.getchannel(3))`, which I believe it is supposed to get the alpha channel of the target image.

This leads me to believe that the image in question is lacking an alpha channel. But the image in question does in fact have an alpha layer.

What is going on?

Comment: Where is the image in question please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell for example it would complain with [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ijn5rpnxqPIoqyiY6syJ1FI7UgzRDr41/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what is wrong. The image you shared is greyscale with alpha channel, so it has 2 bands (LA), not 4 (RGBA).

If you expect a 4 channel RGBA image, you should convert it to that when you open it with:

```
im = Image.open('input.png').convert('RGBA')
```